# Force 32 bits compilation in MSVC 2010 commandline

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, 32-bit, cl

Is there an option to specify in MSVC 2010 commandline executable to force the 32-bits compilation? If so, what is it?

Thanks by advance force your help,

Regards.

Comment: I'm very confident MS has an info page on the web for this. Or the tool can print a list of its options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commandline for compiling 32bit needs an additional `/D "WIN32"`

This will simply define `WIN32`. Macros like `INT_PTR` will be interpreted differently for 64-bit versus 32-bit. For example, `INT_PTR` is defined as follows:

```
#if defined(_WIN64)
    typedef __int64 INT_PTR, *PINT_PTR; //64bit
    ...
#else
    typedef _W64 int INT_PTR, *PINT_PTR; //32bit
    ...
#endif
```

In addition, the link option for 64-bit includes `/MACHINE:X64`

For 32-bit it must be changed to `/MACHINE:X86`

In Visual Studio you can create a sample project, then in Project Properties it shows commandline option for C/C++ compile and link.